# Get UIButton Text from sender

Tags: iphone, uibutton, sender

How can i obtain the text of a UIButton in my

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender
```

method?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What about this:

```
- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; 
  NSString *buttonTitle = button.currentTitle;
}
```